# socket is not defined while running a server on Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, chat

I am trying to create a chat application using node js and mongodb. I am looking on a tutorial for this. I couldn't solve a error that states socket is not defined while running my file server.js. The code in server Js is

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
console.log(mongo);
mongo.connect('mongodb://@127.0.0.1/chat',function(err,db) {
    if(err) throw err;  
    client.on('connection',function() {     
        //Wait for Input
        socket.on('input',function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

});

The error is created when i wanted to listen socket on input.When i try to define socket as
`socket =io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');`  It again gives error stating io not defined. Isn't io global on nodejs?

Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: Are You using express ?

Comment: Please provide more detailed code of server.js

Comment: I don't see where you define your `io` variable

Comment: I am not using express. I am following a tutorial where express is not mentioned

Comment: @Loupax how should i define my io. ISnt io a global variable ???

Comment: IO is not a global variable you have to define it inside server.js like I do in the following code.

Comment: I got my solution. The socket is returned in callback function while doing connection . Like this, client.on('connection',function(socket) . anyways thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try as below if you are using express.

```
var express  = require('express'),
, app        = express()
, server     = require('http').Server(app)
, mongo      = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
, io         = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log("Server Running on port 3000");
});   


mongo.connect('mongodb://@127.0.0.1/chat',function(err,db) {

      io.sockets.once('connection', function(socket) {

       io.sockets.emit('new-data', {
        channel: 'stdout',
        value: "My Data"
     });

   });

});
```

In you view.html

```
   <html>

   <head>
     <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>

     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
     var streamer = $('#streamer');

     socket.on('new-data', function(data) {
        streamer.val(data.value);
     });
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="streamer"> </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```